# eclipse job hanging ui after join

Tags: java, eclipse, jobs, rcp

I have situation like, once copying of items is completed it has to change the ui. I have created a job to copy the items and joined job so that until its completed it will not modify the ui. But ui is getting hanged until copying operation is completed. Here is my code

```
private void copyItems(SelectDTO selection, TreeViewer viewer) {
    try {
        Job job = new Job("test") {
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

                ISafeRunnable runnable = new ISafeRunnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                    //copy items
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleException(Throwable exception) {


                    }
                };
                SafeRunner.run(runnable);
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {

            }

        };
```

I have joined job in addJobChangeListener

```
job.addJobChangeListener(new IJobChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void sleeping(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void scheduled(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void running(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void awake(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void aboutToRun(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        job.schedule();
        job.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

After calling this method i am updating the ui. What changes i can do to stop hanging of ui? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `join` like that. You are scheduling the job and then immediately waiting for it to finish which will block the UI until the jobs ends.

You can add code to the `done` method of the job change listener to do processing when the job has finished.

So something like:

```
job.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter()
   {
     @Override
     public void done(IJobChangeEvent event)
     {
       // TODO Your work here
     }
   });

job.schedule();
```

I have used `JobChangeAdapter` here rather than `IJobChangeListener` directly as it provides default implementations of the methods you don't need to use.

An alternative is to use `Display.asyncExec` in the `Job` code to run some code in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i am changing color of ui once job is completed. If i call ui method inside done(event) its not changing color. If i call after, it its getting hang again. @greg-449

Comment: The job change listener isn't guaranteed to run in the UI thread. You will need to use `Display.asyncExec` in the `done` method if you want to update a UI object. Have you checked the `done` method is actually being run? I don't know what you mean by 'call after it'?

Comment: yes you are right! i was calling directly within done method, forgot to add Display.asyncExec... thanks :)